# umbraco from webform to mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, content-management-system, umbraco

I have installed Umbraco 7.2 manually using [this guide](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Installation/install-umbraco-manually). I opened the website using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web. I was following along with the videos on Umbraco site and when I reached the Developer series, Surface Controllers (more specifically on [creating the Model](http://umbraco.tv/videos/umbraco-v7/developer/fundamentals/surface-controllers/creating-the-model/)), when he created a class (model) in the Models folder, he gets:

```
namespace nameOfProject.Models
{
    public class nameOfModel
    {
      //
    }
}
```

On the other hand, I get this:

```
public class nameOfModel
{
    public nameOfModel()
    {
       //
    }
}
```

In addition, when he creates the View, the intellisense brings up a lists with more options than what I get, for example, he keys in `@Html.TextBoxFor ...`  but when I try to enter it, it's not listed!.

My guess is that it's not recognized as an MVC website. Although I have already sent the defaultRenderingEngine at Umbraco's config file to MVC.

P.S. I don't want to create an MVC solution via VS, but i'd rather have the installation manual since I've tried hopelessly installing using Nuget.

I am really confused and would like to get continue these tutorial series but I am lost due to the reasons mentioned above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition and creating a new ASP.NET application using the "Empty" template and than add "Umbracocms" via Nuget ? I just did this yesterday using VS2013 Ultimate and I was up and running in a few minutes.

Comment: @MKhan Thanks for your response. I can only use visual studio 2012.